# Using an image as a submit button

Tags: html, css

If I want to make my own clickable buttons, I can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button">Sign up</a>
```

Where CSS rules for `a.button` causes the link to be shown as a button. If I apply the same trick to `<input type="submit" />`, I get the button image but it is shown on top of the default submit button and the cursor doesn't change to a hand like it does on `<a>` tags.

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use appropriate CSS properties such as

```
border: none;
background: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
```

to remove the default styles from your `input type="submit"` button.

Answer (score 15):

You could use an `input type="image"` instead.

It is used like this:

```
<input type="image" src="{your image}" alt="{alternate text}" />
```

- [`input type="image"` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`input` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: I've never thought about the `image type`. Did the job!

Answer (score 6):

```
<button id="bar" type="submit"><img src="foo.img" /></button>
```

this creates a submit button with an image inside.

and if you want to change the cursor when you mouseover the cursor use this css.

```
button#bar:hover{cursor:pointer}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough, to use an `<input type="submit" />`:

```
input[type=submit] {
    background: transparent url("path/to/image.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 331px; /* height of the background image */
    width: 500px; /* width of the background image */
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cQaHs/).