# How can I use images in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images :

```
<img src="{% static "img/lt.png" %}" />
<img src="{% static "img/en.png" %}" />
<img src="{% static "img/ru.png" %}" />
```

I need them to be in the form, however I want there to be no submit button - when user clicks on the image the form gets submitted. Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an image as a submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283360/using-an-image-as-a-submit-button). Or [Submit Button Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772326/submit-button-image). Or [button image as form input submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381609/button-image-as-form-input-submit-button).

Answer (score 5):

Use `input` with `type="image"` to your problem

```
<input type="image" src="YourImage" />
```

Comment: +1 for engaging brain before answering.

Comment: I don't know why -1, but ok..

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript click handlers to the images that submit the form using javascript.

```
    <img src="{% static "img/ru.png" %}" onclick="submitForm();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

This can also allow you to modify any potentially hidden input fields before the submit occurs.