# Way to keep input type 'submit' for post reasons but use image as button?

Tags: php, html, css, input

Making a grades display project that uses php mainly. I have made images as buttons for other things, but ran into a wall where I cannot seem to change the two input buttons into 'images of buttons' I have tried other suggestions of using the `type=image` but it would not post properly

So is there a way to change the image while maintaining the `type='submit'` scenario. Or an alternate way to make sure its POSTs properly. The part after is whatever its trying to post to to trigger the grade fetch system. Thank you for any help.

**Code follows:**

```
// the image button im trying to apply
        <a  href='logout.php'><img class='loggers' src="img/logout.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/logout2.png'"onmouseout="this.src='img/logout.png'" style="width: 11%; height: 6%"/></a>

    <form class='options' action="" method="post">

        //change these to images while maintaining 'submit' type

        <input type="submit" name ="grades" value="Display Grades"
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="password" value="Change Password">
    </form>

<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['grades'])) {
        $id = $login_session;
    $dbhost = 'xxxx.xxxxx.com';
    $dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
    $dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        mysql_select_db('grades_db');
        $sql =  "Select student_id, course_id, prelim, midterm, avg_pre_mid, post_removal, pre_final, final_grade, remarks FROM `grades`
        WHERE `student_id` ='".$id."';";
        $retval = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if (!$retval) {
            die ('No Grades Yet');
        }
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><tr><td></td><td>Student ID</td><td>Subject</td><td>Preliminaries</td><td>Midterms</td><td>Average of Preliminaries and Midterm</td><td>Post Removal</td><td>Pre-Finals</td><td>Finals</td><td>Remarks</td></tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{$row['student_id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['course_id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['prelim']}</td>
                <td>{$row['midterm']}</td>
                <td>{$row['avg_pre_mid']}</td>
                <td>{$row['post_removal']}</td>
                <td>{$row['pre_final']}</td>
                <td>{$row['final_grade']}</td>
                <td>{$row['remarks']}</td>
              </tr>";       
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
    mysql_close($conn);
    }
```

Comment: Don't publicly post your dbhost username/password. Please redact!

Comment: thank you for the reminder and warning

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283360/using-an-image-as-a-submit-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I can't identify any clear advantage to wrapping any of these buttons in a form object, unless you have additional data that needs to be sent to the server more privately (using POST). That being said, everything below is optimized to work with form submission back to a PHP script but should be easily modified to work without it.

JQuery has a really easy way to handle something like this. Here's how it works.

First, make sure JQuery gets loaded with your page. Because JQuery is pretty big and is used pretty widely, I like using a CDN for this.

```
<?php // Your entire page, up to the closing body tag... ?>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php // anything that comes after your closing html tag... ?>
```

Adding the script call for JQuery at the end helps with page loading time (front end libraries like JQuery can be heavy and cause the page to take a lot longer to load if called at the top of the document).

At this point, you can start using JQuery. It can look intimidating at first, but with a little practice you can do fantastic things really quickly with it.

The first thing to do is replace the submit button with the image and give the form and the image each an id that we can use to work with it through JQuery:

```
<?php
/*
Make sure you set your action to the route that will handle the form!
If you plan on having one route handle all form actions, you'll need 
to add another hidden field to the form so you can tell which form it
came from and route accordingly.
*/
?>

<form class='options' action='somewhere.php' method='post' id='view-grades-form'>
  <input type="hidden" name='grades' value='<?php $student_id
  // Or wherever you are storing what user's data you're looking for ?>'>
  <img class='loggers' src='img/logout.png' id='view-grades-submit-button'>
</form>
```

Were I in your shoes and were I building the navigation this way I would create a new form just like this for each button you want to use.

It's generally good form to avoid using % heights and widths on raster-based images (png's, jpeg's, gif's, bmp's, tiff's) unless you are using them as background images (not this case for this one). Using % width and height on images can stretch and distort them in awful ways. Try to steer clear of that avenue. Given that logout.png is already the size you want it to be, you might consider either styling it with its existing dimensions or just leaving the height and width off all together.

The next thing to do is to is write a wee little bit of Javascript using the JQuery library. At the bottom of the page, between the JQuery call and the closing body tag, you might add something like this:

```
<?php // JQuery above... ?>

<script>

// Initialize JQuery.
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Add event handlers to take care of events involving the button.
  // eg. mousein, mouseout, click.
  // Note that we can bind these actions to the button through its id. :)
  // Switch images when the image is moused over.
  $('#view-grades-submit-button').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/logout2.png');
  });

  // Switch images back when the mouse leaves the button.
  $('#view-grades-submit-button').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/logout.png');
  });

  // Submit the form when the button is clicked.
  $('#view-grades-submit-button').click(function(){
    // We can select the form object using JQuery and make JQuery submit it.
    $('#view-grades-form').submit();
  });
  };

</script>

<?php // </body> below... ?>
```

Last (and potentially least, depending on how you like things so far) is styling. If you have any additional styling you want to do, put it in a set of style tags inside the  tag, below the  tag. Given that you have classes and id's set up (classes can be applied to any number of objects whereas id's must only be used once per page) modifying any style settings for your form objects should be a breeze. Eg:

```
<style>
/* CSS starts off pretty simple. If you want to do something for all instances of a specific tag, you'll type something like this: */
body {
/* Put your styling options here. */
}

/* For classes, start with a period (.): */
.options {
/* Put your styling options here. */
}

/* And for ID's, start with a #: */
#options {
/* Put your styling options here. */
}
</style>
```

Two little side notes that aren't directly attached to your question but are relevant to your code:

1. Your SQL statements are ripe for the SQL injection picking. Look up "PHP prevent SQL injection attack" on Google and follow the instructions. This will save you from having to answer really awkward questions ranging from [why people's data was stolen to why your web server hosting content for a child porn ring](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/). If your answer involves using question marks (?'s) in the SQL query you're heading in the right direction.
2. Make sure to never ever ever post credentials to anything online (like $dbhost, $dbconnection, and $dbuser) as no amount of additional security measures can prevent people from getting into your system with working credentials.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually. Keep your input type to submit but change the look and feel with CSS. Here is a live example - http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cQaHs/

```
input[type=submit] {
background: transparent url("path/to/image.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
height: 331px; /* height of the background image */
width: 500px; /* width of the background image */
```

}

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283480/3007014

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, small concern but can i shrink the size of the button because now it is way larger than the logout button and also will i be able to apply the mouse-over and mouse-out functions like same in logout hyperlink image before it?